# Translate Symfony 4 / twig

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I translate my string using the following instruction:

```
{% trans into lang %}hi{% endtrans %}
```

My doubt is, theres a way to translate strings inside a block? like this:

```
{{ include('user/_form.html.twig', {'button_label': 'Update'}) }}
<button class="btn  btn-primary submit-user"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> {{ button_label|default('Save') }}</button>
```

I load the text from a external yaml.

Thanks

Kind regards.

Comment: Use filter "trans" `button_label|default('Save')|trans` https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html#twig-templates

Comment: This works when you use translation as locale, but i use translation as a value managed by the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

I created a **LocaleSubscriber** listening onkernelRequest to the value of **Accept-language** in every request header, and automatically change the locale.

This way, you can rely on `|trans` in twig to translate to the right locale

Here the code:

```
class LocaleSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
private $defaultLocale;
private $supportedLanguages;

public function __construct($defaultLocale = 'fr')
{
    $this->defaultLocale = $defaultLocale;

    $this->supportedLanguages = ['en', 'fr', 'es'];
}

public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event): void
{
    if (null !== $acceptLanguage = $event->getRequest()->headers->get('Accept-Language')) {
        $locale = Locale::acceptFromHttp($acceptLanguage);
        if (\strlen($locale) > 2) {
            $locale = substr($locale, 0, 2);
        }
        if (\in_array($locale, $this->supportedLanguages, false)) {
            $event->getRequest()->setLocale($locale);
        } else {
            $locale = $this->defaultLocale;
            $event->getRequest()->setLocale($locale);
        }
    }
}

public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
{
    return [
        // must be registered before (i.e. with a higher priority than) the default Locale listener
        KernelEvents::REQUEST => [['onKernelRequest', 20]],
    ];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @SilvioQ advised you, you can use `trans` filter, *but with `locale` argument*, which contains `lang`:

```
{{ include('location/_form.html.twig', {'button_label': 'Zapisz'|trans([], null, lang)}) }}

<button class="btn btn-primary submit-user"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> {{ button_label|default('Zapisz'|trans([], null, lang)) }}</button>
```

... where `lang` is string (which looks like `'en'`, `'fr'` or another locale, managed by user) or variable, that contains that string.

See [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15413487/4695280) here.

Sure, you should validate locale first as it comes from user, according to you.