# Symfony Translation - Translate a PDF generated in a command

Tags: php, symfony, localization, internationalization

I have a symfony command line calling an external service which inject by the dependency injection the Translator service.

In this service, I want to change the language of my generated pdf, but it is not taking into account the setting of my local and always use the fallback `en`

```
    protected function generatePdf ($data)
    {
        $this->translator->setLocale($data->getCustomer()->getLanguage()->getLocale());

        $view = $this->environment->render('TestBundle:Pdf:test.html.twig', [
            'data' => $data
        ]);

        $path = $this->pdfPathFolder.'/'.$data->getCode().'.pdf';
        $this->loggableGenerator->generateFromHtml($view, $path, []);

        return $path;
    }
```

When I get the local after the set, I get indeed my new value: `it`, but my pdf is still generated in English.

What can I do to translate my PDF generated in CLI? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tee only way I have found to deal with it, is to force the locale in twig like in this post

[Forcing the Twig Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15266673/forcing-the-twig-locale)